# Contour detection

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I could not understand how contour detection algorithm works on a 2D graph generally. Do the Contour detection algorithms check all points in the space to find each contour line? Can someone explain intuitively?

Comment: You mean something like Canny?

Comment: Ander Biguri, I have edited the question

Comment: Humm your question is way more interesting that what I understood. I don't know how to answer it but ill try to make some research. Nice question.

Answer (score 0):

A lot will depend on precisely what you application is. Are you after all the contour lines or just a single one? What is the data you start with - points arranged on a regular grid,  random samples or perhaps a function you can evaluate at any given point. Information about how well the data behaves is also useful - does is have a few big peeks or is it very bumpy.

The main algorithms involve some form or zero-following, say we want to follow the zero contour. There are two main tasks finding an initial point and following round the contour.

For example consider that we have data arranged on a regular grid and have a starting point in one grid square. You can examine neighbouring squares and look at the sign of the function at the corners. If the corners are all positive or all negative we know the contour can not go through the square and we ignore that square. If the contour is nicely behaved there should be  exactly two square with sign changes, choose one, move to that square and repeat. Eventually you will follow the contour back to the start or possibly an edge of your domain.

Finding starting points is trickier. You can look along the edges of your domain, or use some form of sampling.

Comment: I've replied on the other question as that is more specific. Being monotonic it is simple to find the starting points and do the zero following.